# Java does opening an already open file throw an exception or wait

Tags: java, file-io

Let's say I have two processes running (A and B). A has opened a file. If B also tries to open the file does B wait until A closes the file or does B throw an exception? Or does the file system through some magic (like creating in memory copies and buffers) try to let both processes open the file at the same time?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could simply test this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both threads can open the same file.

no errors are thrown.

see below:

the output of following program is:

process 1 opened file

1

2

3

process 2 opened file

1

2

3

process 1 closed file

process 2 closed file

the contents of test file "/tmp/test1.txt" are: 1 2 3

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TwoThreadsOneFileExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Process p1 = new Process("1");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);

        Process p2 = new Process("2");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);

        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(20000);


    }
}

class Process implements Runnable {


    String name;

    public Process(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            processFile();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private void processFile() throws InterruptedException {

        String fileName = "/tmp/test1.txt";

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            System.out.println("process " + name + " opened file");
            stream.forEach(System.out::println);
            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("process " + name + " closed file");

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this behave the same even if they are two different processes on the os (two jar files started separately) instead of two threads?

Comment: yes. two different processes can open the same file simultaneously